# In AEM 6.1, campaigns always showing first teaser

Tags: aem

I have one created one campaign and underneath that I have created three teasers(each of them having different content, third teaser is default). I have linked first two teasers to two different segments and default is not assigned to any teaser. But every time my page is loading, I am seeing the first teaser(even though segments not resolving the client context). Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing segments in same browser/window in which you have configured segments then you might see this problem. Open page in another browser or clear localStorage of your browser (to reset clientContext) and try again.